# SCSS: multiple box-shadow declaration in mixin

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a following mixin for box-shadow:

```
@mixin box-shadow($horizontal, $vertical, $blur, $spread, $r, $g, $b, $a, $inset:"") {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $horizontal $vertical $blur $spread rgba($r, $g, $b, $a) unquote($inset);
    box-shadow: $horizontal $vertical $blur $spread rgba($r, $g, $b, $a) unquote($inset);
}
```

It works fine if I use it like this, for example:

```
@include box-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 0px, 0, 0, 0, 0.4)
```

But how can I chain 2 shadows?

Eventually I want to have a CSS like that, for example:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) inset;
```

I tried it with the following code:

```
@include box-shadow(0px, 2px, 4px, 0px, 0, 0, 0, 0.4), box-shadow(0px, 0px, 6px, 2px, 255, 255, 255, 0.5, inset);
```

But that didn't work. So, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to change your mixin to use a variable parameter. 
Something like this.

```
@mixin box-shadow($params...) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $params;
  -moz-box-shadow: $params;
  box-shadow: $params;
}
```

This would allow you to use commas in the arguments.

And you would use the mixin like this:

```
@include box-shadow(0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.5)) ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible. please see below article for better explanation
http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/multiple_shadows.asp